# How to query check the constraint is valid or not

Tags: postgresql

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8157a4c1823635980019f3bdb1fa6835)
How to query postgresql to check the constraint is valid or not.

```
CREATE TABLE emp (test_check int check ( test_check >1 and test_check < 0 ));
```

query the constraint:

```
select * from pg_constraint where conname = 'emp_test_check_check';

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
oid            | 24631
conname        | emp_test_check_check
connamespace   | 2200
contype        | c
condeferrable  | f
condeferred    | f
convalidated   | t
conrelid       | 24628
contypid       | 0
conindid       | 0
conparentid    | 0
confrelid      | 0
confupdtype    |
confdeltype    |
confmatchtype  |
conislocal     | t
coninhcount    | 0
connoinherit   | f
conkey         | {1}
confkey        | [null]
conpfeqop      | [null]
conppeqop      | [null]
conffeqop      | [null]
confdelsetcols | [null]
conexclop      | [null]
conbin         | {BOOLEXPR :boolop and :args ({OPEXPR :opno 521 :opfuncid 147 :opresulttype 16 :opretset false :opcollid 0 :inputcollid 0 :args ({VAR :varno 1 :varattno 1 :vartype 23 :vartypmod -1 :varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 :varnosyn 1 :varattnosyn 1 :location 46} {CONST :consttype 23 :consttypmod -1 :constcollid 0 :constlen 4 :constbyval true :constisnull false :location 58 :constvalue 4 [ 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]}) :location 57} {OPEXPR :opno 97 :opfuncid 66 :opresulttype 16 :opretset false :opcollid 0 :inputcollid 0 :args ({VAR :varno 1 :varattno 1 :vartype 23 :vartypmod -1 :varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 :varnosyn 1 :varattnosyn 1 :location 64} {CONST :consttype 23 :consttypmod -1 :constcollid 0 :constlen 4 :constbyval true :constisnull false :location 77 :constvalue 4 [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]}) :location 75}) :location 60}
```

get the check definition:

```
select pgc.conname as constraint_name,
       ccu.table_schema as table_schema,
       ccu.table_name,
       ccu.column_name,
       pg_get_constraintdef(pgc.oid) 
from pg_constraint pgc
join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = pgc.connamespace
join pg_class  cls on pgc.conrelid = cls.oid
left join information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
          on pgc.conname = ccu.constraint_name
          and nsp.nspname = ccu.constraint_schema
where contype ='c'
order by pgc.conname;
```

return:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------+------------------------------------------------
constraint_name      | emp_test_check_check
table_schema         | public
table_name           | emp
column_name          | test_check
pg_get_constraintdef | CHECK (((test_check > 1) AND (test_check < 0)))
```

Similar question:

```
CREATE TABLE emp1 (test_check int check ( test_check >1 and test_check > 10 ));
```

can postgresql deduce from above check constraint to
`CREATE TABLE emp1 (test_check int check ( test_check > 10 ));`

if It can, how to query it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to apply the constraint (dynamically) on values before inserting or updating data?

Comment: I saw it on twitter. now I cannot found it.... you can query postgresql to return result: weather this constraint is valid or not. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: now the constraint is invalid. there is no int >1 and also <0. therefore the constraint is invalid. but postgresql should know this check constraint is invalid.

Comment: [From the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html) "*convalidated bool  - Has the constraint been validated? Currently, can be false only for foreign keys and CHECK constraints*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I attached the dbfiddle link. even i validate the constraint, `convalidated` still return true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `boolean` expression is *valid* for a [`CHECK` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS).

> a Boolean (truth-value) expression.

**Postgres does not attempt to simplify your expression.** It's your responsibility to provide sensible expressions. The expression is parsed and checked to be *valid*, then stored in an internal format. (So every stored expression is *valid*.) But not simplified. Not even the simplest cases like `CHECK (true AND true)`.

You already have a working query to retrieve `CHECK` constraints, but I would use this faster query not involving the (bloated) `information_schema`:

```sql
SELECT c.conname AS constraint_name
     , c.conrelid::regclass AS table_name  -- schema-qualified where needed
     , a.column_names
     , pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) AS constraint_definition
FROM   pg_constraint c
LEFT  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT string_agg(attname, ', ') AS column_names
   FROM   pg_attribute a
   WHERE  a.attrelid = c.conrelid
   AND    a.attnum = ANY (c.conkey)
   ) a ON true
WHERE  c.contype = 'c'  -- only CHECK constraints
AND    c.conrelid > 0   -- only table constraints (incl. "column constraints")
ORDER  BY c.conname;
```

Aside:

> It should be noted that a check constraint is satisfied if the check expression evaluates to true or the null value.

Comment: hi, Erwin. This question would be most funniest question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996169/some-of-range-composite-type-operator-only-check-the-elements-of-composite-type